# Appending String After Line Break

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

[image]

I want to achieve this(Shown in the above picture) line break and concatenation for NSAttributedString. The second city, in this case, Paris should start from the top but it starts from the right side of Germany because Germany starts from the new line that is why Paris is getting appended on the right side of Germany instead of starting from the top.
Any help would be appreciated.

Following is my code:

```
    /// Flight Attributed String
    var flightAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "");

    /// From City
    let fromCityAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0, weight: .medium)];
    let fromCity = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\((self.route?.fromCity)!)  ", attributes: fromCityAttributes);

    /// From Country
    let fromCountryAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : kAppSecondryIconColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8.0)];
    let fromCountry = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\((self.route?.fromCountry)!)", attributes: fromCountryAttributes);

    /// From City Complete
    fromCity.append(fromCountry);

    /// To City
    let toCityAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0, weight: .medium)] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    let toCity = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\((self.route?.toCity)!)  ", attributes: toCityAttributes);

    /// To Country
    let toCountryAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : kAppSecondryIconColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8.0)];
    let toCountry = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\((self.route?.toCountry)!)", attributes: toCountryAttributes);

    /// To City Complete
    toCity.append(toCountry);
    // print("toCity.accessibilityFrame: \(toCity.accessibilityFrame)");

    /// Plain Icon
    let imgAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    imgAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "iconAirplane.png")
    imgAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -5, width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
    let imgAirplane = NSAttributedString(attachment: imgAttachment)

    /// Making Complete Flight String
    flightAttributedString.append(fromCity);
    flightAttributedString.append(imgAirplane);
    flightAttributedString.append(toCity);

    /// Draw the result in a lblFlight
    // self.lblFlight.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
    self.lblFlight.attributedText = flightAttributedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use stack views here, it would definitely gives you more flexibility.

Here is the final result:

[image]

And the implementation would be like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let flightBoardView: FlightBoardView = {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(FlightBoardView())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    private func setup() {
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        flightBoardView.set(fromCountry: "Germany", fromCity: "Frankfurt", toCountry: "France", toCity: "Paris")
        view.addSubview(flightBoardView)
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        flightBoardView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        flightBoardView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And your `FlightBoardView` could be a subclass of `UIView` (in case you want to reuse it somewhere later in your code and avoid duplication) and look like this:

```
class FlightBoardView: UIView {

    private lazy var departureStackView: UIStackView = {
        $0.distribution = .fill
        $0.alignment = .leading
        $0.axis = .vertical
        $0.spacing = 5
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [fromCountryLabel, fromCityLabel]))

    private lazy var destinationStackView: UIStackView = {
        $0.distribution = .fill
        $0.alignment = .leading
        $0.axis = .vertical
        $0.spacing = 5
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [toCountryLabel, toCityLabel]))

    private lazy var containerStackView: UIStackView = {
        $0.distribution = .fill
        $0.alignment = .center
        $0.axis = .horizontal
        $0.spacing = 20
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [departureStackView, planeImageView, destinationStackView]))

    private let fromCountryLabel: UILabel = {
        $0.textColor = .black
        $0.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(UILabel())

    private let fromCityLabel: UILabel = {
        $0.textColor = .lightGray
        $0.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(UILabel())

    private let toCountryLabel: UILabel = {
        $0.textColor = .black
        $0.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(UILabel())

    private let toCityLabel: UILabel = {
        $0.textColor = .lightGray
        $0.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(UILabel())

    private let planeImageView: UIImageView = {
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        $0.image = UIImage(named: "airplane")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        $0.tintColor = .systemBlue
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return $0
    }(UIImageView())

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    private func setup() {
        addSubview(containerStackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            containerStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            containerStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            containerStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            planeImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            planeImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: planeImageView.widthAnchor),
        ])
    }

    func set(fromCountry: String, fromCity: String, toCountry: String, toCity: String) {
        fromCountryLabel.text = fromCountry
        fromCityLabel.text = fromCity
        toCountryLabel.text = toCountry
        toCityLabel.text = toCity
    }
}
```

Of course you could do the same with Storyboards and xib files if you prefer, but at least that gives you a working example and you can adjust to fit your needs.

I also added the `set(fromCountry:fromCity:toCountry:toCity:)` method to allow you to change your data easily from the parent view.

Comment: Hi @alex-linaries, first of all, thanks a lot for sharing the code script. it really helps a lot. Can you please let me know how can I increase the height of FlightBoardView if the text is more than the current width of the screen? Secondly, how can I find the height of the FlightBoardView because I have to set my TableView Cell height Accordingly?